# How to convert dict values from list to tuple

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, tuples

I need to convert the values of a dictionary I have into a tuple from a list.

My code is below:

```
import io

opened_infocsv = io.StringIO('''"ID","Name","Type 1","Type 2","Generation","Legendary"
720,"HoopaHoopa, Confined","Psychic","Ghost",6,"TRUE"
1,"Bulbasaur","Grass","Poison",1,"FALSE"
681,"Aegislash, (Blade Form)","Steel","Ghost",6,"FALSE"
413,"Wormadam, Plant","Bug","Grass",4,"FALSE"
643,"Reshiram","Dragon","Fire",5,"TRUE"
678,"Meowstic, Male","Psychic","",6,"FALSE"''')

def read_info_file(filename):
    idb = {} #Declares empty dict to be written to.
    #opened_infocsv = open(filename, 'r') #opens an argued .csv file witH INFO format.
    info_string = opened_infocsv.readlines()

    #opened_infocsv.close()
    for i in range(1,len(info_string)):
        splitline=info_string[i].replace("\n",'').replace('"','').split(',')
        for loc,i in enumerate(splitline):
            if i=="":
                splitline[loc]=None

        if len(splitline)==7:
            splitline[1]=splitline[1]+","+splitline.pop(2)
            splitline[0],splitline[4]=int(splitline[0]),int(splitline[4])
        if len(splitline)==6:
            splitline[0],splitline[4]=int(splitline[0]),int(splitline[4])
        if splitline[5] == "TRUE":
            splitline[5]= True
        else:
            splitline[5] = False

        idb[splitline.pop(1)] = splitline
    print(idb)
```

Currently, my output is a dictionary with this format:

```
{'HoopaHoopa, Confined': [720, 'Psychic', 'Ghost', 6, True]}
```

All I want to happen is that list of values to be converted into a tuple.

I tried `tuple(idb.values())` but it doesn't seem to be working.

Finally, I need the solution to be able to be added AFTER the last line `("idb[splitline.pop(1)] = splitline")` as I need to be able to pop the list *before* converting it.

Comment: tuple(list(idb.values())[0]) -> (720, 'Psychic', 'Ghost', 6, True)

Comment: that didn't do anything

Comment: Assuming `{'HoopaHoopa, Confined': [720, 'Psychic', 'Ghost', 6, True]}` as idb, try again `tuple(list(idb.values())[0])`

Comment: @jyotish where did you add the code? I added it underneath idb[splitlines.pop... and it didn't change anything.

Comment: What do you need finally when you print(idb), is it {'HoopaHoopa, Confined': (720, 'Psychic', 'Ghost', 6, True)} or just (720, 'Psychic', 'Ghost', 6, True).

Comment: I need to print the entire dictionary, with the list changed to tuples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty basic, just build a new dictionary where every value has been converted to a tuple and rebind the name of your old dictionary.

Here's a short demo:

```
>>> d = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]}
>>> d = {key:tuple(lst) for key, lst in d.items()}
>>> d
{'a': (1, 2, 3), 'b': (4, 5, 6)}
```

I employed a dictionary comprehension. If you are uncomfortable with those, the following code achieves the same thing.

```
>>> d = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]}
>>> new_d = {}
>>> for key, lst in d.items():
...     new_d[key] = tuple(lst)
... 
>>> d = new_d
>>> d
{'a': (1, 2, 3), 'b': (4, 5, 6)}
```

edit: I just realized my answer is partial since there's an additional question in the last line of your post. I don't really follow what you are talking about there, so I'll leave my answer as-is for now.

Comment: I tried implementing your solution and am getting a syntax error. Is there anything wrong with this: 

    new_idb = {}
    for key, 1st in idb.items():
        new_idb[key] = tuple(1st)
    print(idb)

Comment: you wrote tiple instead of tuple

Comment: @ruckarucka `1st` is not a valid variable name since it starts with a number. My `lst` starts with a small L. Also `tiple` is a typo, you need `tuple`.

Comment: that was a typo on this site, the code has been fixed and I still get the error. Is it because there are two arguments being provided to the for loop? Key and 1st? EDIT: Oh, I see. I will correct the variable name. Thank you!